# Django REST Framework (DRF): TypeError: register() got an unexpected keyword argument 'base_name'

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have updated to [**`djangorestframework==3.11.0`**](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/) from older version. Now I've got this error,

> TypeError: register() got an unexpected keyword argument 'base_name'

```
Traceback
  ...
  ...
  ...
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/home/abu/projects/django-example/django2x/urls.py", line 21, in <module>
    path('sample/', include('sample.urls')),
  File "/home/abu/.virtualenvs/django-example/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/urls/conf.py", line 34, in include
    urlconf_module = import_module(urlconf_module)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 955, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 665, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 678, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/home/abu/projects/django-example/sample/urls.py", line 6, in <module>
    router.register(r'musician', MusicianViewset, base_name='musician')
TypeError: register() got an unexpected keyword argument 'base_name'
```

Answer (score 75, accepted):

From the [release notes of Django RestFramework](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/community/release-notes/#390) and [`DRF 3.9` announcement](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/community/3.9-announcement/#router-argumentmethod-renamed-to-use-basename-for-consistency) they mentioned that

> Deprecate the `Router.register` **`base_name`** argument in favor of **`basename`**. [#5990](https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/issues/5990)

Which means, the argument **`base_name`** is no longer available from **`DRF=3.11`** onwards and use [**`basename`**](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/routers) instead

So, Change your router config as,

```
router.register(r'musician', MusicianViewset, basename='musician')
router.register(r'album', AlbumViewset, basename='album')
```